# Unable to load images over HTTP even after adding exceptions

Tags: ios, twitter, react-native

In my app I want to display Twitter user's profile images, but Twitter provides the links via HTTP:

http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/843199968018157568/zHovYMDk_normal.jpg

I've updated my info.plist to include the domain Twitter uses for their profile images:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>pbs.twimg.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I'm still unable to load the images however. I've also tried `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, but that didn't work either.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: paste your code where you are used that url.Did you got any message from console regarding transport security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [check the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) you'll see that images links are returned with https links:

```
...
"profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/530814764687949824/npQQVkq8_normal.png",
"profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/530814764687949824/npQQVkq8_normal.png",
...
```

So use the value from `profile_image_url_https` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks Terence, can't believe I missed that! Do you know why the exception in my info.plist wasn't working?

Comment: Sorry JmJ - I'm not an iOS developer.